# microk8s ingress results in operation time out

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-service, microk8s

Why is the connection refused each time I try to connect to a nodeport exposed service on MicroK8s?

Here is the following deployment, service and ingress:

```yaml
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx-container
        image: 'nginx'
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: nginx
  type: NodePort
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx.info
  labels:
    app: 'nginx'
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: 'nginx.plz'
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/"
        backend:
          service:
            name: 'nginx'
            port:
              number: 80
```

I've included the following line my `/etc/hosts` file as well:

```
127.0.0.1 nginx.plz
```

However, when I try to reach the site I continue to get the following error:

```
 curl -v -H "host: nginx.plz" 10.152.183.60 

*   Trying 10.152.183.60...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connection failed
* connect to 10.152.183.60 port 80 failed: Operation timed out
* Failed to connect to 10.152.183.60 port 80: Operation timed out
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.152.183.60 port 80: Operation timed out
```

Is anyone familiar with setting this up on microk8s? I did see a few other questions such as this one: https://serverfault.com/questions/1032572/microk8s-deploy-application-not-working but it didn't have a solution

EDIT: I have enabled the microk8s ingress as well.

Answer (score 0):

i just deployed your configuration on my local microk8s and was able to hit the endpoint. The only difference i see is that I have enabled Microk8s ingress (https://microk8s.io/docs/addon-ingress),with the ingress add on enabled, it creates a namespace called ingress with ingress controller and it which watches for new Ingress rules (you have already defined them) and configures its underlying proxy to enact the corresponding routes.

To enable ingress on microk8s, do the below, everthing else is taken care by Microk8s. Our ingress resource has the rules, ingress controller will map it.

```
microk8s enable ingress
```

```
k get all  -n ingress
NAME                                          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/nginx-ingress-microk8s-controller-rmgs4   1/1     Running   1          1d

NAME                                               DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR   AGE
daemonset.apps/nginx-ingress-microk8s-controller   1         1         1       1            1           <none>          1d
```

Also, note your ingress addon can be configured to expose TCP and UDP services by editing the nginx-ingress-tcp-microk8s-conf and nginx-ingress-udp-microk8s-conf ConfigMaps respectively, and then exposing the port in the Ingress controller.

```
k get cm -n ingress
NAME                                DATA   AGE
nginx-load-balancer-microk8s-conf   0      1d
nginx-ingress-udp-microk8s-conf     0      1d
nginx-ingress-tcp-microk8s-conf     8      1d
ingress-controller-leader-public    0      1d
```

The other solution to enable the traffic is to enable the metallb loadbalancer.
(https://microk8s.io/docs/addon-metallb). Once done, check your ingress/service (kubectl get svc/ingress) and it should show your endpoint either of the solution should work without much manual intervention.

```
curl http://10.152.183.102:80
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
    body {
        width: 35em;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>

<p>For online documentation and support please refer to
<a href="http://nginx.org/">nginx.org</a>.<br/>
Commercial support is available at
<a href="http://nginx.com/">nginx.com</a>.</p>

<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, I do have ingress enabled. I can post any additional information that might help. I have tried removing/uninstalling and restarting the pc since you said it works for you

Comment: Check the ingress controller logs, do you see traffic coming in? Also check the configmaps in the ingress namespace, to see if the 80 is mapped. Also, check to ensure there is nothing else running on port 80 (apache2 or any other app etc) or any other app running on anyother namespace on port 80.